# Where Can I Download Spring Roo Since There's No Download Button on the Official Site?

Tags: spring-roo

I'm interested in downloading Spring Roo for an old project, but I've noticed that the official Spring Roo website doesn't seem to have a direct download button or link. I've checked the website thoroughly, and it appears that the download option is not available.

Can anyone provide information on where I can download Spring Roo? Is there an alternative official source, a mirror site, or a specific repository that I should use to obtain the tool? I want to make sure I'm downloading it from a reputable and trustworthy source.

Any assistance in finding the right download location for Spring Roo would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you can try from the archived GitHub repository https://github.com/spring-attic/spring-roo/tags

As the download zip is the source code of the project and not the built project, you'll need to follow the contributors guide to build it locally and try to run it.

https://github.com/spring-attic/spring-roo/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.adoc

However, this is a discontinued project and maybe you'll not be able to download some of the dependencies.

If you are finally able to run the Spring Roo shell, I'll recommend you to use the `push-in` command to remove all the Spring Roo annotations and continue working as common Spring Boot project.

Check `push-in` command documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-roo/docs/current/reference/html/#push-in

Hope it helps!